# Dice throwing distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Dice is thrwn $n<100$ times. Each side of the dice has probability of landing $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6 \neq 0$. What is the probability that the sum of all the throws (we are summing dice values) is less than $t\in[n,6n]$?

I would like to solve this in R, so that I can change the parameters ($p_1,p_2\ldots$ and $t$ and $n$) and it calculates the answer quickly.

My solution so far:
First of all I calculate the mean
$$n\left( \sum_{i=1}^{6}ip_i\right)$$
That is the value that represents the skew of the graph. Now I need to choose a correct distribution (normal, multinomial, etc distributions), where parameters would be $n$, $6n$ and the mean. After that I could simply calculate the distribution $F(t)$ and that would give me the answer. I could use some help on the distribution part and writing the program in R.

Comment: Looks like a multinomial distribution, no? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have given you this as the answer to the [question you deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780547/dice-throw-distribution):

Three R functions

```
# function creates distibution of probabilities for sum, starting at 0
throwsdist <- function(throws=1, faces=6, facedist=rep(1/faces,faces)){
    if(length(facedist) != faces){ stop("wrong number of face probabilities")}  
    if(sum(facedist) != 1){ stop("face probabilities do not add up to 1")} 
    probvector <- c(1, rep(0,faces*throws))
    if(throws > 0) {
        for (t in 1:throws){
            probvector <- rowSums(matrix(rbind(rep(0,faces), probvector %*% 
                      t(facedist))[1:(faces + faces^2*throws)], ncol=faces))
           }
       }
    probvector
   }  

# function for probability of particular values given dicedist starting at 0
ddice <- function(x, probs0n=dicedist) {
    ifelse(x %in% 0:(length(probs0n)-1), probs0n[x+1], 0)
   }  

# function for cumulative probabilities given dicedist starting at 0
pdice <- function(q, probs0n=dicedist) {
    x <- floor(q)
    ifelse(x < 0, 0, ifelse(x > length(probs0n)-1, 1, cumsum(probs0n)[x+1] ))
   }
```

Set up the distribution

```
# example: 9 throws and a distribution with mean 3, so min value 9 max 54 
dicedist <- throwsdist(throws=9,faces=6, facedist=c(0.4,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2))
```

Examples at each end of probabilities and cumulative probabilities:

```
> ddice(7:10)
[1] 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000262144 0.000589824
> ddice(53:56)
[1] 2.304e-06 5.120e-07 0.000e+00 0.000e+00
> pdice(7:10)
[1] 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000262144 0.000851968
> pdice(53:56)
[1] 0.9999995 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Examples of mean calculation

```
> sum((9:54)*ddice(9:54))               # mean of sum of 9 throws 27  
[1] 27
> sum(1-pdice(0:54))                    # mean of sum of 9 throws 27  
[1] 27
```